# Get public posts from facebook account

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to simply get a list of  public facebook posts, but it turns out to be harder than expected. After running into dozens of different approaches / answers, I decided to try the Facebook PHP SDK - with no result:

```
$appID     = 'MY_APP_ID';
$appSecret = 'MY_APP_SECRET';
$userID    = 'TARGET_USER_ID';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appID, $appSecret);

$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

try {
    $session->validate();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    // Session not valid, Graph API returned an exception with the reason.
    echo $ex->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    // Graph API returned info, but it may mismatch the current app or have expired.
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}

try {
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/' . $userID . '/feed');
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
} catch(\Exception $exception) {
    print_r($exception);
}

// result always is an empty GraphObject
print_r($graphObject->AsArray());
```

My target is to simply read out all public posts of $userID, but despite not getting any errors with this code, it $graphObject is always empty. I already used my private facebook account and made some public test-posts, whitout a result.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I get a simple list of all the posts?

Edit: It seems that a lot of documentations / "howtos" refer to an old facebook PHP SDK, where there is only 1 single class (called Facebook). Are there any examples with the new SDK?

**In the end, my only target is to read the posts from one single user (which I have full access to) like you would with twitter. If there are easier ways, I can switch to those as well. It's not supposed to be an application for multiple users - just a way to read out your own fb-posts.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can´t get public posts of a User profile without authorizing that specific User with `user_posts`. And you can also just use `/me/feed`. More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed

What you need to do:

- Authorize the user with `user_posts`
- Extend the User Token and store it in your database
- Use `/me/posts` with the stored Token to get the entries

Information about Tokens can be found in the following articles:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: How exactly do you get that kind of authorization? I mean, if I wan't to display my own facebook posts on my website (for example), is there a key/secret that I can find in my settings to use for the application? I easily was able to do this on twitter, and I just need to recreate that for facebook. The "app" is not supposed to be used by any user.

Comment: you have to use facebook login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.3

Comment: I might be incredibly dense today, but what I need isn't a user login for each user, but a (permanent) facebook feed to a single user. If a login is required something is wrong. I'll look through those links, maybe I can find the information there - but even the first one states that a token is only valid for hours / 60 days. How are "permanent" page-feeds on external websites implemented? It can't be this hard! But I'm reading through the links now, maybe I can see the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: i know that. you MUST authorize your user in order to get access to the posts/feed. i repeat: login IS required. and you are right, the extended user token is valid for 60 days, after that you have to refresh it. you can´t do that automatically. user feeds are not really made for showing on external websites, those entries are kind of "personal". if you want a permanent solution, just use a facebook page. extended page tokens are valid forever. although you can also just use an app access token for page feeds.

Comment: make sure you understand the difference between user profiles and facebook pages.

Comment: Alright, then that's the problem - I don't use facebook at all, so I assumed it's the same! I'm probably talking about facebook pages then.

Comment: Yes, "pages" was  the keyword here. I didn't know the difference between the two. Getting a page feed from a public page works as expected (I always used the user-id before, trying to get my own feeds). Thanks a lot, and sorry for the trouble / missunderstanding! It's just as easy as I expected it to be, as soon as you use the right identification ;)